# console.log printing 'undefined' when calling this on a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript, I can't find a clear answer to what's going on here:

```js
function bike() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var name = "John";
var obj1 = {
  name: "Sam",
  bike: bike
};
var obj2 = {
  name: "Paul",
  bike: bike
};

bike(); // undefined
obj1.bike(); // Sam
obj2.bike(); // Paul
```

I don't understand why it's printing 'undefined' on the terminal instead of 'John'

Comment: but here it shows `John`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: its printing John

Comment: @DevsiOdedra any idea why it would show undefined when I run it on my terminal?

Comment: @ASDFGerte I see thank you!

Comment: Please also note, that in a browser context, you collide with `window.name`. You can write to the property, but it is a setter, that autoconverts to string. Just as a side note.

Comment: it prints john, because the snippet is not in strict mode (undefined/null this gets converted to window), and global variables get added to window. It **should** throw, "cannot read property `name` of `undefined`". I don't know what your terminal is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this Behaviour,

```
function bike() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

var name = "John";
var obj1 = {
  name: "Sam",
  bike: bike
};
var obj2 = {
  name: "Paul",
  bike: bike
};

bike(); // undefined here it refers to (**this**).name
        //if you run the same in browser console 
        // you will get jhon
        // but in node there is no window object
        // that's y you are getting undefined in node terminal

obj1.bike(); // Sam
obj2.bike(); // Paul
```

Plz refer the link ASDFGerte suggested for more

Comment: `this` defaults to the global `window` object when not called from an object method.

Answer (score -2):

it's Simple you just write

```
window.name
```

window.variableName it is used to print global variable

Comment: `this` defaults to `window` if you're not in an object method.